# Sending files to view from controller

Tags: c#, .net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to send a file from an MVC 5 controller to an angularjs client.  I need to specify the filename in the response.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult DownloadAttachment([FromUri] long NoteId)
{
    var attachment = db.tcp_tahGeneral_downloadNotesAttachment_API(NoteId).First();
    var path = attachment.AttachmentLocation;

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        byte[] file = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(file, 0, file.Length);

        return new FileContentResult(file, attachment.AttachmentFileType);
    }
    return null;
}
```

This sends the file but will not allow me to specify the new file name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property `FileDownloadName` to set filename in [FileContentResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-2.1), you can try the below return statement.

```
return new FileContentResult(file, attachment.AttachmentFileType) 
           { 
              FileDownloadName = "myfilename.myext"
           };
```